# Finding path to DLL from ASP.Net project

Tags: asp.net, dll, appdomain

I have a MVC website from which I want to load a DLL from another project in the solution. This  would be easy in a console app. The catch is I want to load the dll in an app domain (so can't use a project or file reference). The website project and the DLL project don't trust each other you see.

I have used build events to copy the DLL into the bin/Debug or bin/Release folder however when I run the app Calls to Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location gives some temp folder with only the website.DLL the other dll in another folder, with no obvious relationship between the folders.

**How do I find the path to a dll, to load it in an app domain, with no direct references, in a asp.net MVC site?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path);
```

or use HostingEnvironment.MapPath

```
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
```

or (if you use ASP.NET core)

```
// DI
IHostingEnvironment _appEnvironment;
Path.Combine(_appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath, "bin", "Debug", "YourDllName.dll");
```

where path is something like `var path = "~/bin/Debug/YourDllName.dll";`